# Say, hypothetically, there were 4 seconds in 1 minute instead of 60 seconds. How many seconds would 24 hours (1 day) be?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Let 1 minute = **4 seconds**.

Let 1 hour = **60 minutes**.

Let 1 day = **24 Hours**.

How many seconds would be in **1 day**?

Comment: Are we allowed to assume that 2 minutes = 8 seconds, 3 minutes = 12 seconds, etc.?

Comment: Yes, Dave. We are allowed to assume that.

Comment: This is not mathematics. It is arithmetic. Voting to close.

Comment: $$4\cdot 60\cdot 24\cdot 1=5760$$

Comment: Voting to reopen, as I cannot find anything in the guidelines that say a question has to be about mathematics above a certain level. Plus, there are many questions on this site about basic arithmetic ideas, and for this particular question there's even an appropriate tag -- unit-of-measure.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro it says at various places  though that some context, motivation and work should be provided. The question should be closed. The argument for closing might needs some elaboration, but this does not change the basic fact that as is the question should be closed;

Comment: @SamuelAntonov post your attempt next time, as some people downvote if askers do not post their attempt.

Comment: Google dimensional analysis. You will find it highly relevant!

Comment: Enough with the downvotes already! It’s a new user who probably didn’t know the rules.

Comment: @TonyK This is not mathematics. It's mathematics.

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{1 \text{ minute}}{4 \text{ seconds}}$$
$$\frac{4 \text{ seconds}}{1 \text{ minute}}*\frac{60 \text{ minutes}}{1 \text{ hour}} = \frac{240 \text{ seconds}}{1 \text{ hour}}$$
$$\frac{240 \text{ seconds}}{1 \text{ hour}} * \frac{24 \text{ hours}}{ 1 \text{ day}} = \frac{5760 \text{ seconds}}{1 \text{ day}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Reasoning from elementary school :

So these new seconds are 15 times longer, hence the number of new seconds in a day is fifteen times less: i.e.
$$ \frac{24\times 60\times 60}{15} =\frac{ 8\times 3600}5=5760. $$